# Options to develop professionally with Microsoft tools and Technologies without spending a lot?

Tags: windows

I would like to develop applications for the Windows platform & at the very least I need a server based Windows OS (2008), SQL Server, IIS and Visual Studio. Looks like VS2010 professional alone will cost over $1K. Is there a cheaper option to get hold of Microsoft software? I remember long time ago there was an MSDN subscription option which allowed user access to server based OS and other server applications with restrictive licensing that was cost effective. I don't see that option anymore. Moreover, I am not a student & I understand Microsoft provides software at discounted rates for students. Any pointers?

Comment: MSDN Essentials provides all of this for $799.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off with the [Express versions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/) of these products, at little to no cost.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer based on the comment "MSDN Essentials provides all of this for $799" you made above.

Answer (score 1):

[**BizSpark**](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/)

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Faqs.aspx#Startup-Question12), emphasis added.

> **What Microsoft software is included?**
>
> All the software included in the
>   **Visual Studio Team System Team Suite**
>   (VSTS) with MSDN Premium subscription
>   Expression Studio (Version 2), plus
>   VSTS Team Foundation Server Standard
>   Edition - for the entire development
>   team The development tools provided
>   are the same as those in MSDN Premium
>   subscription, plus VSTS Team
>   Foundation Server. However, there are
>   features of MSDN Premium (such as
>   support and internal use licenses)
>   that are not included in BizSpark
>   Production license use rights, to
>   deploy, host and support Startup’s
>   "Software-plus-Services" applications
>   for delivery over the Internet, using
>   the most current releases of the
>   following products: **Windows Server**
>   (all editions), **SQL Server** (all
>   editions), BizTalk Server, and Office
>   SharePoint Server for hosting. To
>   deploy in production, a Startup may
>   self-host or select an authorized
>   BizSpark Hosting Partner through the
>   BizSpark Network Partner directory.

The [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) of some of their software is available for free. However, you will still need to purchase the operating system with this option and will not get access to premium features.

Answer (score 1):

The option for installing your own Server OS / SQL Server and alike you are probably thinking of is the personal http://technet.microsoft.com, which can be used for personal pruposes such as development and learning, but can not be used for production.

I personally have a copy to run Hyper-V, multiple server 2k3 images, a server 2k8 image, and multiple SQL servers + 1 oracle 11g. The number of licenses per OS / server application etc varies from 1 to 10 but most are 10 (except things like exchange, why would you want 10 exchanges?)

The price when I purchased it was £204 for the initial annual license, and an slightly reduced annual subscription fee.

It also comes with application licenses such as all of office, project, visio etc.

What it does not include is the development tools at all - to keep the cost down on those you have to use express or pay the money.